Tabkey "Grid Definitions - Grid Lines" etabs version 2020
I used etabs version 2018 "Grid Definitions - Grid Lines" to edit data in that table. But with the etabs 2020 version, that data cannot be changed. Can you help me?
I am a developer, before I used etabs version 2018 "Grid Definitions - Grid Lines" to edit data in that table. But with the etabs 2020 version, that data cannot be changed. Can you help me?
